# Как организовать поиск по базе данных SQL по нескольким столбцам

Tags: sql, база-данных, поиск

Все не могу придумать вариант поиска по БД по параметрам чтобы один поисковый запрос мог фильтровать предыдущий запрос. Если кто сталкивался помогите

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Veils\Desktop\Veilsapp\Veilsapp\Minerals.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Miner] WHERE Color LIKE N'%" + Ptb1 + "%'", con);
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Miner] WHERE MainColor LIKE N'%" + Ptb2 + "%'", con);            
        SqlDataReader val = com.ExecuteReader();
        SqlDataReader val1 = com1.ExecuteReader();            
        while (val.Read ()&& val1.Read())
        {
```

Comment: `SELECT FROM (SELECT ... WHERE ...) WHERE ...`

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста подробнее ваш кейс и укажите СУБД.

Comment: Нет смысла. Поместите все условия отбора в один запрос.

Comment: Пытался прикрепить пикчу но она не грузится решил добавить код но он не решение так как ExecuteReader надо закрывать и как поместить все условия можно код примерный?